# Troubleshooting Progress Bar Transition Issue in React Code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm facing an issue with my progress bar code, where the transition doesn't start intermittently unless I wrap setStartTransition within setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame. I have provided an example on CodeSandbox: [Progress Bar Buggy](https://codesandbox.io/s/progress-bar-buggy-3pby7c). (after loading ,refresh codesandbox browser)

In the ProgressBar.js file:

```
`import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function ProgressBar({
  onProgessComplete,
  startFilling,
  duration
}) {
  let [startTransition, setStartTransition] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (startTransition || !startFilling) {
      return;
    }
    //setTimeout(() => {
    setStartTransition(true);
    //});
  }, [startTransition, startFilling]);

  let reactStyle = {
    transitionDuration: `${duration}ms`
  };

  console.log("before render", startTransition);

  return (
    <div className="bar">
      <div
        onTransitionEnd={() => {
          console.log("ended");
          onProgessComplete();
        }}
        style={reactStyle}
        className={["progressBar", startTransition && "progressBar--filled"]
          .filter(Boolean)
          .join(" ")}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
}`
```

And in the App.js file:

```
`import "./styles.css";
 import  { useState } from "react";
import ProgressBar from "./progressBar";

const progressData = [
  { id: 1, duration: 1500 },
  { id: 2, duration: 2000 },
  { id: 3, duration: 1000 }
];

export default function App() {
  let [progressComplete, setProgressComplete] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="barWrapper">
        {progressData.map((ele, i) => {
          return (
            //rendering the list here
            <ProgressBar
              key={ele.id}
              duration={ele.duration}
              startFilling={(() => progressComplete === i)()}
              onProgessComplete={() => {
                setProgressComplete((state) => ++state);
              }}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}`
```

However, my understanding is that calling setStartTransition(true) after render should start the transition without the need for a timeout. I have fixed the code here: [Progress Bar Fixed](https://codesandbox.io/s/progress-bar-99nxwl).

Can someone please help me understand what's happening? Is it an issue with useState?